# Text rendering is jagged

Tags: css, fonts

The font 'exo' taken from Google/fonts and doesn't look too bad on my desktop, it looks perfect on my htc smartphone.

however it looks like an army of caterpillars have been chomping on it when viewed on my laptop.

I've tried anti aliasing, text smoothing by adding shadows and blurs,
nothing is working.

Any other tips or tricks or should I justtry find a replacement :'(

Comment: +1 for "looks like an army of caterpillars have been chomping on it"

Comment: Check this out: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en

Comment: I assume you're using Google Chrome browser?  Is that correct?

Comment: Primarily chrome yes. Thanks ranveer, checked that linked its definately not a problem with the encoding.

Comment: Post code that demonstrates the issue, identify the browser and platform where the problem appears, and be descriptive rather than poetic when specifying your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with some fonts. To get around this, you have two ways:

1. Convert the font using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ and use it.
2. Download the font you need and then use it by using src: url('path')

Hope this works.

Comment: Does not work. If you think it does, please provide a playground page the proves it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; to the body.

It may just be the font, some nice google fonts that I tried and tested are;

Source sans pro
lato
Open sans

Hope this helps in some way